# FQL is_app_user is not working anymore

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have a few Facebook apps, and I use the following FQL to get the list of app users:

SELECT uid,name FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 1

and it works fine, but now I created a new app, and the above FQL always returns empty and I know for a fact that I have friends using the APP,

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your new app using version 2.0 of the API? If so the only values in the 'friend' table should be users of your app - is that working for you?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by adding "user_friends" to the list of requested permissions, I didn't need this permission in Graph API V1.0